# Wifi very slow on 16.04

Tags: 16.04

after two years i decided to install ubuntu on my Samsung ultrabook (series 5) again. Yesterday i did a fresh installation of 16.04 and everything works great but wifi does not. It is very very slow. So slow i am not able to download a 30MB file.

I found a script for getting the most important wifi-Information so i hope someone could help me finding the problem.

This is the output of the script:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/23375528/

Thanks for help

Comment: See my answer at http://askubuntu.com/questions/839731/slow-ubuntu-16-04-wireless-info-speeds/839757#839757

Comment: Genius, seems to work :) thanks to @waltinator