# Slow connection with Broadcom BCM43142 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, drivers, 16.04, broadcom

I have recently switched to Ubuntu 16.04 and I'm having problems with my wireless connection. I'm using a Broadcom BCM43142 wireless card and using the Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA driver.

The wireless connection always shows at low signal. Sometimes it works at adequate speed, but most of the time the connection is slow (much slower than on Windows in which I have a dual boot partition).

I have tried uninstalling/reinstalling the driver. I have also already tried disabling IPv6 and also tried to avahi daemon fix to no avail.

I've run the following wireless script and this is the output

http://pastebin.com/BU5ZZJcY

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Comment: To close voters. The Broadcom driver is already installed.

Comment: Check your MTU, and fix it. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/839731/slow-ubuntu-16-04-wireless-info-speeds/839757#839757

Answer (score 4):

In Debian 9 I used:

sudo apt install broadcom-sta-dkms

and it did the whole trick for my hp ProBook6570b laptop. I was getting a near 20Mbits/s before. I ran the command and rebooted the laptop for a clean start. After this all of a sudden I saw a 180Mbits/s

I am happy!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Pilot6's answer below could cause problems in maintaining a network connection, resulting in both an inability to install `broadcom-sta-dkms` and connect to wi-fi to continue to diagnose. Marcel's solution here worked well for me after a fresh install of Pop! OS with an ASUS/Broadcom external wi-fi setup.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install a newer driver by running

```
sudo apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt install broadcom-sta-dkms
```

It helps to improve speed on some Broadcom chipsets.

Answer (score 0):

I was with the same problem and found this 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2175345.
Here the guy had a problem because the hardware encrypting. The solution given was change the driver parameter do disable it through modprobe... "nohwcrypt=1"

Knowing that the problem is with the encryption algorithm, searching a little bit more, https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2162616, some guy solved the problem with something more easier and faster. He changed the wireless security setting to

> "pure WPA2-PSK (AES). No mixed mode, no TKIP"

So I did it and it's working with full speed again. However, the price is lowering the Internet security, be advised.

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced the same problem for years in my hp laptop.The problem was  not with the software but the hardware.
My laptops wlan card was having only one black colored antenna usually other laptops has 2 antenna wires.My laptop was having a different form factored(smaller) wlan card.
so what i did was simply disconnect the antenna from one slot of the card and placed in the antenna slot(has one wire but 2 slots on the card).
please remove your laptops case and check if yours is also the same case.