# Slower connection with Broadcom BCM43142 on Ubuntu 16.04 on Asus

Tags: networking, 16.04, drivers, broadcom, asus

I'm having problems with my wireless connection on my Asus F555LD-XX108H.

I'm using a Broadcom BCM43142 wireless card and I have a very slower speed (20 Mb) with respect of my other pc when I use wifi.

I tried to change the MTU according to this thread [Slow Ubuntu 16.04 Wireless Info Speeds](https://askubuntu.com/questions/839731/slow-ubuntu-16-04-wireless-info-speeds/839757#839757) but it doesn't work for me.

I ran the Ubuntu wireless-info script and pasted the contents into a pastebin: http://pastebin.com/3stxmTup

It is possible that being my problem in the range 50-90 Mbps (5 GHz), the driver doesn't work in this frequency?

Someone can help me please?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced the same problem for years in my hp laptop.The problem was not with the software but the hardware. My laptops wlan card was having only one black colored antenna usually other laptops has 2 antenna wires.My laptop was having a different form factored(smaller) wlan card. so what i did was simply disconnect the antenna from one slot of the card and placed in the antenna slot(has one wire but 2 slots on the card). please remove your laptops case and check if yours is also the same case.

Comment: what do you even mean?

Comment: i dont know where that came from bro.By any chance do you know php?i have posted a question on stack overflow ,no answers yet.so i asked.